# Why element is not found in table?

Tags: javascript

Here is a table  with rows (tr).

I try to reset background color for all table rows:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          if (rows[i].hasAttribute("background-color")) {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

          }
        }
```

The row exmaple is:

```
<tr style="background-color: rgb(232, 229, 216);">
```

Comment: Can you share your table element ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `hasAttribute` checks for attribute, e.g. `style`, not for css rule applied `background-color`. Use class to toggle style instead

Comment: If you did console.log(rows[i].hasAttribute("background-color")) you would have seen there is no such attribute. Justinas answer about add and a remove a class is okay, rows[i].classList.add("classname") or rows[i].classList.remove("classname"). In your stylesheet you can put .classname{ background-color: rgb(232, 229, 216); } Also have you tried if (rows[i].style.backgroundColor != "transparent") { instead of           if (rows[i].hasAttribute("background-color")) { if you just wanted to reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the style being set and assign it null if it's truthy:

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#demo tbody tr')

for (let row of rows) {
  if (row.style.backgroundColor) {
    row.style.backgroundColor = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="baseline">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: red"><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: blue"><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: green"><td>Baz</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="demo">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: red"><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: blue"><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: green"><td>Baz</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It should be noted that inline styles are generally ill-advised. More favored is the use of classes on an ancestor element and/or descendant objects and to toggle that.